# Inserting data into a access database using parameters

Tags: c#

What am I not understanding in the following code:

```
using (OleDbConnection connectionFail = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Fail_DB.mdb"))
            {
             connectionFail.Open();
              var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SUMMARY (A, B, C) VALUES (@A, @B, @C)");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@A", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "A";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@B", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "B";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@C", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "C";
                try
                {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                connectionFail.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                }
                connectionFail.Close();
                }


          }
```

I just want to add data to a SUMMARY table. I get ExecuteNonQuery:Connection property has not been initialized. What am I not understanding?

Comment: You never *set* the command's connection. Anyway, SqlCommand is for SQL Server. You should use OleDbCommand

Comment: FYI, never call `Dispose` like that, instead initialize the `SqlCommand` in a nested using block. That will handle cleanup.

Comment: @AluanHaddad may I ask why?

Comment: Because `IDisposable`s need to be disposed and because you can forget to do so, or do so incorrectly, C# has the `using` statement which automates the process. This improves maintainability, raises the abstraction level slightly, is idiomatic, and does not hijack exception handling machinery to perform expected cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection was created but never *set* on the command object. BTW SqlCommand is a SQL Server Client command.

Instead of :

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SUMMARY (A, B, C) VALUES (@A, @B, @C)");
```

Use

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SUMMARY (A, B, C) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",connection);
```

Access doesn't support named parameters in *SQL queries*. The parameter values will be substitued by position.